# How Can I do a trigger keyboard (left and right arrow) in flash CS4 for next / prev frame? Like a PowerPoint Presentation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

**StackOverflow** community.

I'm full newbie, but I like CS4 and Javascript code. I wanna spend my time practicing this. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

add a KeyboardEvent. and getting a keyCode, handle as follows.
notice. need to add a `stop();` code on frame 1 of your MovieClip.

check out this my sample code: [simple_ppt](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-d9c4e345.html)

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownHandler);

function onKeyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        trace("left!!!");
        if(myMovieClip.currentFrame > 1)
        {
            myMovieClip.prevFrame();
        }
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        trace("right!!!");
        if(myMovieClip.currentFrame < mc.totalFrames)
        {
            myMovieClip.nextFrame();
        }
    }
}
```